# Custom Python Tk menu

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, tk-toolkit

When I try to assign a function with an argument in add_command constructor that function gets executed on menu launch.

So my question is: Is there any way to loose the "one function per menu item"? as in a full fledged menu that would add quite an overhaul.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import os
from Tkinter import *

def runCommand(app):
  os.system(app + " &")

def runBrowser():
  app = "firefox"
  runCommand(app)
def runTerminal():
  app = "terminology"
  runCommand(app)
def runFileManager():
  app = "xfe"
  runCommand(app)
def runEditor():
  app = "atom"
  runCommand(app)

root = Tk()
root.title("Root Menu")

menubar=Menu(root)
appsmenu=Menu(menubar)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Root Menu", menu=appsmenu)

appsmenu.add_command(label="Terminal", command=runTerminal)
appsmenu.add_command(label="Editor", command=runEditor)
appsmenu.add_command(label="File Manager", command=runFileManager)
appsmenu.add_command(label="Browser", command=runBrowser)
appsmenu.add_separator()
appsmenu.add_command(label="Close Menu", command=root.quit)

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post a minimal example of your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to assign a function with an argument in add_command constructor that function gets executed on menu launch.

When you add a command, you must give it a *callable*. If you want to pass arguments, you can do so by creating a callable either with [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) or [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

For example, if you wanted a single function that can be given the command to run, you can do it like this:

```
def run_command(command):
    print "running...", command

appsmenu.add_command(label="Terminal", command=lambda: run_command("Terminal"))
```

If you want to create the menu items in the list, you can bind the value of a variable by providing it as a default argument to `lambda`:

```
for label, cmd in (("Browser", "firefox"), 
                   ("File Manager", "xfe"), 
                   ("Editor", "atom")):

    appsmenu.add_command(label=label, 
        command=lambda command=cmd: run_command(command))
```